# making a flutter music app using audioquery ,listview not showing

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a list view of songs using audioquery but the list is not showing I ran it with no-null safety, this is my tracks.dart file whats wrong with my code?
I am getting only the appbar in the output

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_audio_query/flutter_audio_query.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class Tracks extends StatefulWidget {
  _TracksState createState() => _TracksState();
}

class _TracksState extends State<Tracks> {
  final FlutterAudioQuery audioQuery = FlutterAudioQuery();
  List<SongInfo> songs = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTracks();
  }

  void getTracks() async {
    songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();
    setState(() {
      songs = songs;
    });
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: Icon(Icons.music_note, color: Colors.black),
        title: Text('Music App', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
        itemCount: songs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: songs[index].albumArtwork == null
                ? AssetImage('assets/img.jpg') as ImageProvider
                : FileImage(File(songs[index].albumArtwork)),
          ),
          title: Text(songs[index].title),
          subtitle: Text(songs[index].artist),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: getTracks should return Future<void>

Comment: did that no change

Comment: can you trying printing songs variable before `setState` to see if data is returned from the api?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions for your problem would be using using only the `songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();` line in the *initState()* function.

But if you want to keep using your *getTracks()* function, I think you have to declare the songs variable (at the first line of the method) and then use the '**this**' keyword in the *setState()* method (to specify the global songs *List reference* being initialized).

Comment: no change i tried putting songs = await audioQuery.getSongs(); in init too but await wont work without async

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the getSongs() is from the audioQuery package. but I was reading the documentation and I noticed that method returns an future instance. I advice you using FutureBuilder and not a Listview directly (and the songs variable as the value of future parameter).